# NullPointerException Inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, file, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I want to populate listview with catalog names which are inside other specific catalog that my application is creating in other activities.

Here's the doInBackground method:

```
@Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ArrayList<String> wynik = new ArrayList<String>();
        File katalog = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/DBConnector/Projekty/");
        File[] projekty = katalog.listFiles();
        for (File projekt : projekty) {
            if (projekt.isDirectory()) {
                wynik.add(projekt.getName());
            }
        }
        return wynik;
    }
```

It's throwing NullPointerException. As far as I know, even if there were no folders there it just should leave the ArrayList empty and pass it on (I'm using if(result.isEmpty()) later in onPostExecute to give info to user about that or actually populate listview if it's not empty - very similar code worked in other place, where I populated listview with data from resultset). Still, there are multiple folders there. I'm afraid I made some stupid mistake, but I just can't see it. I would appreciate some help.

EDIT: The thing that helped was restarting eclipse. Should have thought about it first though I still have no idea how it could have happened.

Comment: Is katalog folder exists?

Comment: What do you mean by "It's throwing NullPointerException"? point to the null object please.

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: I'm sorry for posting an uncomplete question, but I thought it's obvious that NullPointerException was pointed exactly at line with for clause. There is no way now to post it anyway, since problem solved itself after restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the logcat it's quite difficult to say for sure.

1. Are you sure you can access external storage? (Manifest Permission)
2. Is File Katalog a valid? or just null?
3. Is File[] projekty returning an empty array?

Use breakpoints and check those points above.

Comment: All those are valid advices and I actually checked it all before posting my question here, so I'm accepting that answer. The thing that helped was just restarting eclipse, as I wrote in the edit.

Comment: I see. I've seen wierd behaviors in Eclipse but never thought restarting it could clear a NullPointerException. Good reference for future.